# What does the Gilbert-Varshamov bound say about random linear codes?

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics, coding-theory

I am trying to understand what the [Gilbert-Varshamov bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound) means for random linear codes, that is, codes that are generated by a random generator matrix $G$ with $$\mathcal{C} = \{\, vG \mid v \in \mathbb{F}^k \,\}$$ or by a parity check matrix $H$ with $$\mathcal{C} = \{\, v \in \mathbb{F}^n \mid Hv = 0 \,\}.$$

Someone claimed that such a random code had an asymptotically good minimum distance according to the GV bound, and I am trying to figure out why that is. Which implications does the GV bound have for random linear codes?

Comment: Is the answer satisfactory? If so, it is good form and helps the site and the volunteers who answer if you accept the answer.

Comment: @kodlu Yes, sorry, didn't have time to read the referenced paper yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof of GV is by using the probabilistic method itself.

In any case, the paper by Barg and Forney (Random Codes: Minimum Distances and Error Exponents, *IEEE Trans. Information Theory*:48(9)) available [here](https://eng.umd.edu/~abarg/reprints/rce.pdf) should be very helpful.

You are looking at the LCE code ensemble.

The abstract of the paper is given below. Two quick definitions:

The RCE (Shannon) ensemble selects a random $(N,M)$ code by selecting $M$ $N-$tuples uniformly at random from $\{0,1\}^N$ (equivalently selecting each of $2^{NM}$ bits uniformly at random) so each possible code has probability $2^{-NM}$ of being selected. The rate $R$ is defined by $M=2^{RN}.$

The LCE ensemble is chosen by selecting the $K$ generating $N-$tuples $g_k$ by selecting each bit in each tuple uniformly at random and then letting the code be the binary linear span of these tuples (with dimension $K$ and $R=K/N$).

*Abstract*—Minimum distances, distance distributions, and error exponents
on a binary-symmetric channel (BSC) are given for typical codes from
Shannon’s random code ensemble (RCE) and for typical codes from a random
linear code ensemble (LCE).

A typical random code of length $N$ and rate $R$ is
shown to have minimum distance $N\delta_{GV}(2R)$, where $\delta_{GV}( R)$ is the
Gilbert–Varshamov (GV) relative distance at rate $R,$ whereas a typical
linear code (TLC) has minimum distance $N \delta_{GV}( R)$.

Consequently, a Typical Linear Code has a better error exponent on a BSC at low rates, namely, the expurgated error exponent.